# Swift function in protocol not called

Tags: swift, protocols

the function `windowDidChangeOcclusionState` never gets called.

```
class MainWindow: NSWindowController, CloseWindowWhenNotFocused {

    static let shared = MainWindow()
    convenience init() {
    let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: DownloadMainView.shared)

    let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: hostingController)
    window.setContentSize(NSSize(width: 800, height: 400))
    window.title = "MainWindow"
    self.init(window: window)

    self.window?.delegate = self
    self.window?.center()

}
```

}

```
protocol CloseWindowWhenNotFocused: NSWindowDelegate{ }

extension CloseWindowWhenNotFocused where Self : NSWindowController{

func windowDidChangeOcclusionState(_ notification: Notification) {
    print(#function)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions cannot override methods. What you're trying to do is not possible. In particular, you can't reliably add an optional delegate callback to every type that conforms to a protocol. It's possible to conform types to protocols in modules other than the one they're defined in. There's no reliable way to do this.